# ListView flutter, how to keep at full height always

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, frontend, flutter-listview

Im trying to remove the scrolling of my ListView widget. Currently, the user only has a small window of tiles to scroll through. The listview data is paged so only shows 20 items at once- i want to show all 20 items and the whole page to scroll, rather than the user scroll through the list view a few at a time. How can i achieve this?

```
return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Constants.listSeparatorGrey,
            ),
            itemCount: pageState.data?.data?.length ?? 0,
            itemBuilder: (context, idx) =>
                itemBuilder(pageState.data?.data?[idx]),
          ),
        ),
        Text('${pageState.data?.total ?? 0} results',
            style: TextStyles.rowHeader(context)),
        Text(
          'Page ${pageState.data?.currentPage()} of ${pageState.data?.pageNum()}',
          style: TextStyles.rowHeader(context),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(width: 20),
            if (pageState.data?.hasPrev ?? false)
              MyButton(
                // isLoading: pageState is Loading,
                type: ButtonType.secondary,
                label: "Previous",
                onPressed: pageApi.prev,
              )
            else
              Container(width: 8),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 8,
            ),
            (pageState.data?.hasNext ?? false)
                ? MyButton(
                    // isLoading: pageState is Loading,
                    type: ButtonType.secondary,
                    label: "Next",
                    onPressed: pageApi.next,
                  )
                : const SizedBox(width: 8)
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Can you provide simplified version ? You can try `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` on `ListView` or just generate items, and use wrap with scrollable widget .

Comment: neverscrollablephysics() does not produce the output i want. That gives the same sized window, only scrolling is harder. I want the size of the list view to be the height of the results

Comment: Can you provide a gif that you are trying to archive?

Comment: I want the user to scroll the layout, not the list

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand you. Just move all your content to ListView. So all your page starts scrolling with content.

```
Widget header = Container(color: Colors.green, height: 100);
List<Widget> content = const [Text("firstCell"), Text("secondCell")];
Widget button =
    const TextButton(onPressed: null, child: Text("Next page"));

List<Widget> widgets = [header] + content + [button];

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('All content in list'),
  ),
  body: ListView(children: widgets),
);
```

Here result:

[All content in ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwIr1.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
I just put the root column in a SingleChildScrollView()
very simple in the end